# JPA Eclipselink NamedQuery vs Query COUNT

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

Cannot get a Integer back from a NamedQuery???

```
@NamedQuery(    name = Comm.COUNTLIKEVALUEINHOLDER,
        query = "SELECT COUNT(c.id) " +
            "FROM Comm c " +
            "JOIN c.element e " +
            "WHERE c.search1 LIKE :search1 " +
            "AND c.search2 = :search2 " +
            "AND c.type = :type " +
            "AND e.holderelement = :holder"
    )

Object q = em.createNamedQuery(Comm.COUNTLIKEVALUEINHOLDER)
    .setParameter("search1", "bla%")
    .setParameter("search2", "bla2")
    .setParameter("type", t)
    .setParameter("holder", h)
    .getSingleResult();
```

I get a Entity back and not a Long or Integer from COUNT Aggregat.

But here I get a Integer back. It's exactly the same query.

```
Object i = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(c.id) " +
    "FROM Comm c " +
    "JOIN c.element e " +
    "WHERE c.search1 LIKE :search1 " +
    "AND c.search2 = :search2 " +
    "AND c.type = :type " +
    "AND e.holderelement = :holder")
    .setParameter("search1", "bla%")
    .setParameter("search2", "bla2")
    .setParameter("type", t)
    .setParameter("holder", h)
    .getSingleResult();
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

em.createQuery is used for creation of dynamic queries. Return type is determined by the return type of the QL language ("SELECT COUNT(c.id)" in the example above).

em.createNamedQuery is used for creation of static queries. Return type can be type casted, for example:

```
Object q = em.createNamedQuery(Comm.COUNTLIKEVALUEINHOLDER)
   .setParameter("search1", "bla%")
   .setParameter("search2", "bla2")
   .setParameter("type", t)
   .setParameter("holder", h)
   .getSingleResult();

Integer count = (Integer) q;
```

`
see also:http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/api